# Function for converting many .dat files to .csv

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I am struggling to write a for loop to convert approximately 100 `.dat` files into `.csv`.

My `.dat` files look like this:

```
% Filename : Spm04A1_00288_00001.tif
% Date & Time : 26-Oct-2021 15:45:01
% X-ray Energy (keV) : 20.000
% Exposure Time (s) : 1.030
% Beam Center : 718.20700, 1572.10000
% Sample to Detector Distance (SDD) (mm) : 2175.520
% Detector Pixel Size (mm) : 0.146
% Photodiode Value : 176453.000
% 10 of Sample : 198187
% 10 of Standard : 1
% q(A^-1) I(q) sqrt(I(q))
0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00
6.78047596e-04    0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00
1.35609519e-03    0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00
2.03414279e-03    0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00
2.71219038e-03    0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00
3.39023798e-03    0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00
4.06828558e-03    0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00
4.74633317e-03    0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00
5.42438077e-03    0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00
6.10242836e-03    0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00
6.78047596e-03    0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00
7.45852356e-03    0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00
8.13657115e-03    0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00
8.81461875e-03    9.12221748e+00    3.23146137e+00
9.49266634e-03    8.47547513e+00    1.27051027e+00
```

The data files consist of X-ray scattering data with three columns (`scattering vector`, `intensity`, and `sqrt(intensity)`. They are the raw data files that were received from a recent scattering trip. In order to process these data files in a different piece of software, I need to convert them into `.csv`.

I was able to edit one file (and add headers) using this code:

```py
headerList = ['q(A^-1)', 'I(q)', 'sqrt(I(q))']

data.to_csv("Spm04A3_00258_00001.csv", header=headerList, index=False)

data2 = pd.read_csv("Spm04A3_00258_00001.csv")
print('\nModified file:')
print(data2)
```

Unfortunately, that is not efficient for converting 100 data files but I really struggle with writing loops. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Please, post samples of the contents of the `.dat` files and the desired output `.csv` files.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the .dat file opened with a texteditor. I'm not sure if that is at all helpful though?

Comment: You might be better off using command line tools such as `awk`/`gawk` or `sed`.

Comment: By the way, if you're running Linux, this would be easily done with this line in bash:

`for f in *.dat ; do echo "q(A^-1),I(q),sqrt(I(q))" > "$f.csv" && tail -n+2 $f
| awk '{print $1","$2","$3}' >> $f.csv; done`

This works because your scenario is only working with numerical data, which allows doing it with simple string manipulations.

Or as @Tony wrote - with a simple `sed 's/\w+/,/' $f > "$f.csv"`

Comment: The data in the  image you posted seems to be already in `CSV` format. You just need to to know what character is being used as the separator for each record.

Comment: I don't believe it is in csv? I right-clicked on the .dat file and opened with textedit. I believe it is tab separated? Maybe I can upload one of the .dat files? Let me explore....

Comment: It doesn't look like tab separated, since the last column of the header is misaligned. It's probably a text format gotten by some `lua` script running on some makeshift device. You just gotta replace the spaces with commas using `sed` and see what happens. Otherwise `awk`, or if you feel it's simpler for you then any of the python solutions provided.

Comment: You could even load the file in to your favourite spreadsheet application as you can specify the field separator when importing it; then save the file as CSV.

Comment: I guess it doesn't even need any kind of conversion. Just copying the files with an extension of `.csv` will do the trick... IMHO.

Comment: @Beth, Do all the `.dat` files have that header line already?

Comment: @accdias I updated the screenshot of an unmodified .dat file. It has several lines of metadata at the beginning of the file which I figured out how to write code to edit the files to remove that. Since the original headers seemed off, I removed them as well and that is why I was including the addition of the new headers within my failed attempt at code!

Comment: Thanks. That is a completely different beast! :-). I will update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Have I mentioned yet that you are my hero, @accdias?? lol

Comment: Answer updated. Can you give it a run and see if it does the trick? I would test it here before if I had one of those files in raw format and not a screenshot.

Comment: @accdias It worked!!! I cannot thank you enough! Now onto the next task of learning to write code to subtract data from one csv file and another and save the result as a new file! So much to learn!

Comment: I'm glad to help, @Beth. Do not hesitate to post new questions as they arise.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @Beth, please consider marking one of the answers as accepted. That way you help others with similar questions find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to loop through each CSV file. I'm going to make some very broad assumptions that are up to you to validate.

```
from pathlib import Path

headerList = ['q(A^-1)', 'I(q)', 'sqrt(I(q))']
csv_dir = Path("/path/where/dat/files/are/located")
for file in csv_dir.glob("*.dat"):
    # each file is of type PosixPath. You can access its parent directory, its name, etc
    # Here I'm placing the CSV file in the same place as the dat file
    csv_file = file.with_suffix(".csv")
    # Add your code here, that loads the dat file
    data = load_the_dat_file(file)
    data.to_csv(csv_file, header=headerList, index=False)
    data2 = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    print('\nModified file:')
    print(data2)
```

I took your code, and put it in a loop. I'm not sure that's what you wanted to achieve, but it's a loop over all the `.dat` files.

Extra:

It's probably not necessary to read the CSV again after that. You can just replace the headers of the data frame:

```
data.headers = headerList
```

Comment: I guess this `csv_file = file.parent / (file.name[:-4] + ".csv")` can be better if you write it as just `csv_file = file.with_suffix('.csv')`.

Comment: Every day you learn something new, right? :D

Comment: Always. :-) `pathlib` is one of my favorite modules, hence my suggestions.

Comment: OP fooled us. The sample data posted already has a header line. :-P

Comment: I expected that, but maybe the header is just wrong? Yeah, this is a 1-liner shell command, since I expect that it might just be a fixed number of spaces (see how the last column in the header is 1 character offset).

Comment: Sorry - that is one that I had tested out a line of code to add a header! I promise I'm not fooling anyone! I'm not nearly skilled enough to even attempt that! lol

Comment: @Beth, don't worry. We are just kidding. That is why it is important to always add a sample of your input data and a sample of the desired output.

Comment: Haha I appreciate all of the help. I attempted to post a question last week but failed miserably. I really want to get better at this and I really appreciate all of the input and feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using standard Python modules only:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import csv

dats = Path('/folder/with/datfiles')
headers = ['q(A^-1)', 'I(q)', 'sqrt(I(q))']

for dat in dats.glob('*.dat'):
    with dat.with_suffix('csv').open('w') as f:
        rows = [
            _.strip().split() 
            for _ in dat.read_text().readlines()
            if not _.startswith('%')
        ]
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(headers)
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

The code above will process any `.dat` file found in `dats` folder and generate a corresponding `.csv` file in that same folder.

`rows` is a list populated with all lines that don't start with a `%` in the current `.dat` file.